# How could I pass 'context' with a stream?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a simple app running that pipes objects through a stream, like so:

```
new ReadStreamThatCreatesData()
.pipe(new TransformerStream())
.pipe(new WriteStreamThatActsOnData()
```

But I want the `WriteStreamThatActsOnData` to have access to a property in from the `ReadStreamThatCreatesData`, without the `TransformerStream` having to know about it or be able to access it. The pseudocode of what I'd want is basically this:

```
new ReadStreamThatCreatesData()
.storeContext((obj) => obj.property)
.pipe(new TransformerStream())
.retrieveContext((obj, context) => obj.property = context)
.pipe(new WriteStreamThatActsOnData()
```

but given the nature of streams I don't really see how that's possible. Does anyone have any smart ideas on how I could do something like this?

Comment: I guess the solution should look more like `a.map(o => ({data:o, context:o.property})).pipe(actOn('data', transformer)).pipe(b)`, but I'm not sure how to write these functions exactly either

Answer (score 0):

One way I can think to do this is to pipe the ReadStreamThatCreatesData to a function that splits it into two different streams: one stream of the context properties you have pulled out of the item and another stream with the remainder of the object. You pipe the second stream into the TransformerStream and then pipe that output along with the context stream through a zip operator that combines the two streams back into one. Then you send that to the WriteStreamThatActsOnData.

I don't think there are built-in node.js functions to do this, but you can use another library such as [RxJS](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS) or [highland](http://highlandjs.org/).

Here's an example implementation with highland:

```
'use strict';

/*

Put this content into input.txt. Make sure there are no blank lines in the file:    

{ "secret": 1, "val": "a" }
{ "secret": 2, "val": "b" }
{ "secret": 3, "val": "c" }
{ "secret": 4, "val": "d" }
{ "secret": 5, "val": "e" }

After running, output.txt should have this content:

{"val":"A","secret":1}
{"val":"B","secret":2}
{"val":"C","secret":3}
{"val":"D","secret":4}
{"val":"E","secret":5}

*/

const fs = require('fs');
const stream = require('stream');
const highland = require('highland');
const input = fs.createReadStream('input.txt');
const output = fs.createWriteStream('output.txt');

function readStreamThatCreatesData() {
  return highland(input).split().map(JSON.parse);
}

class TransformerStream extends stream.Transform {
  constructor(options) {
    if (!options) {
      options = {};
    }
    options.objectMode = true;
    super(options);
  }
  _transform(item, enc, cb) {
    if (item.secret) {
      item.secret = 'removed';
    }
    item.val = item.val.toUpperCase();
    this.push(item);
    cb();
  }
};

function removeSecret(item) {
  delete item.secret;
  return item;
}

function extractSecret(item) {
  return item.secret;
}

const inputStream = readStreamThatCreatesData();
const secretStream = inputStream.fork().map(extractSecret);
const mainStream = inputStream.fork().map(removeSecret);

secretStream.zip(highland(mainStream.pipe(new TransformerStream())))
  .map((combined) => {
    const secret = combined[0];
    const item = combined[1];
    item.secret = secret;
    return JSON.stringify(item) + '\n';
  })
  .pipe(output);
```